# Merge Visual Studio Solution Files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, merge, projects-and-solutions

We have two large solution files that we would like to merge into a single solution.

We could just add the projects from solution A to solution B. But wondering if there is a less time consuming way to do this?

Comment: "less time consuming"? - how long would that take?

Comment: 80 projects VS crashed part way through.. Allways looking for a more efficient way of doing things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved this myself using Perl and some [regex magic](http://blog.tedd.no/index.php/2011/01/06/merging-multiple-visual-studio-solution-sln-files-into-one/)

The script should work for both Windows and Linux, though I developed and ran it on Linux.

Answer (score 8):

I had similar requirement to merge a few .sln files into one (Visual Studio 2013). What I did was:

1. Open one .sln in visual studio [File > Open > Project/Solution...]
2. Open second .sln in visual studio [File > Open > Project/Solution...] *but* select 'Add to Solution' option. You might then get warnings that project of same name already exists - ignore them. If there are duplicate folder names, you may need to resolve them after the projects are added to new .sln file
3. Repeat step 2 for all the rest of .sln files

This worked for me, not sure what would happen in case of duplicate GUIDs though.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite error-prone merging two versions of the same solution file - merging two separate files would be even more error-prone in my opinion.

I know no tools for this - my normal approach has been to use VS itself and manually add the projects.

Answer (score 2):

You can try playing around with this tool:

http://code.google.com/p/merge-solutions/

It can also detect and fix duplicate guilds in projects/solution items that is a common result of project-wide copypaste.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make my own a few days ago
[download source+bin (54KiB)](http://behrooz.id.ir/slnMerge.zip)
(no license/public domain/copyleft/whatever makes you feel good:)

Comment: "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: The link is fixed now.
I should note that, even though I use this along with few similar programs on ~10 sln files and ~2600 csproj files now(post is more than 2 years old) with great success, this is as simple as it gets and you should change it according to your own needs. good luck.